# Checking that two different variables match

Tags: r, dataframe, matching

I have a dataset that I need to run a check of two variables "Call" and "cluster".

I need to check that calls of the same value all have the same cluster number.

The problem is the K-means clustering method I used assigns different cluster numbers each time I run it.

So I need a check that looks at the allele 1 call for example and checks that the numbers are all the same under the cluster call. (the numbers could be listed as 2 one run and the change to 3 if I re-run the code)

**Please see data structure below**

```
structure(list(RFU1 = c(-0.295502405, 0.964070798, 3381.332182, 
3532.769062, 3431.836843, 3242.966511, 2104.791167, 2220.008503, 
3548.252161, 3506.51418, 2290.273178, 2281.587684, -5.64819475, 
-11.73109864, 3784.914039, 3619.00781, 3618.211608, 3248.106466, 
3394.650325, 3339.870196, 2449.202902, 2426.835174, 3432.153478, 
2761.392304, -9.267907504, -7.365704356, 3743.092314, 3787.241702, 
2172.027787, 2096.845649, 2135.649551, 2149.145547, 2293.757257, 
2348.099108, 2321.019045, 2022.168867, -17.93532331, -12.59832941, 
3805.416768, 3498.998138, 2304.597239, 2509.63987, 2181.11547, 
2261.011876, 3432.453036, 3662.758933, 2371.11049, 3068.827061, 
2612.107589, 2687.824075, 3179.315918, 3688.525218, 3465.327523, 
3405.154043, 2535.514915, 2452.200079, 374.435299, 423.6015308, 
3742.515563, 3578.777925, 2634.955017, 2527.514043, 3817.579252, 
3550.999412, -10.72035816, 3294.486334, 3352.40368, 3463.150507, 
3472.576514, 3741.898759, 3571.369947, 3720.645869, 3739.569593, 
3855.583168, 418.6837047, 49.47548241, 2171.034284, 2155.314713, 
3432.363384, 3582.508917, 3425.415274, 3487.203299, 3505.23909, 
3413.342096, 113.5100691, 128.6414053, 2454.588175, 2323.061591, 
3188.705702, 3376.950546, 3291.072437, 3181.001961, 3195.013863, 
3776.919197, 2284.22659, 2277.338631), RFU2 = c(-8.346468029, 
235.4058561, 637.9218251, 650.3759507, 617.4161748, 604.0792911, 
4270.310727, 4199.615749, 689.863543, 712.6144338, 4274.287194, 
4541.168491, -1.626221758, -2.437395631, 802.0941252, 730.5998997, 
686.9037384, 625.8245403, 644.3586836, 642.8833044, 4937.691887, 
5159.479928, 725.4449756, 573.3910899, -4.006398006, 213.2859144, 
739.7910786, 731.0150586, 4408.81923, 4767.533969, 4302.641493, 
4325.913445, 4597.47663, 4666.904418, 4800.357526, 4142.535329, 
-17.23239968, 178.5311942, 778.305843, 743.1438168, 4214.507094, 
4553.703511, 4629.339014, 4459.697405, 661.7299014, 727.1054982, 
4553.170272, 5482.231486, 4520.517999, 4737.802036, 643.3599887, 
726.4314715, 696.5968338, 697.6099599, 411.8118071, 409.4943424, 
5687.32635, 5757.51512, 766.4240193, 779.2403225, 4745.055632, 
4582.267792, 749.5679421, 675.8747055, -7.254521898, 628.3467565, 
631.116767, 672.7064514, 687.2642132, 718.1192917, 731.785499, 
668.3686048, 784.8055727, 791.3155894, 4471.047168, 4501.597841, 
4504.670332, 4442.621066, 682.0632225, 706.6204595, 680.5242182, 
683.9558692, 684.2909706, 618.6535251, 5727.684954, 6098.485474, 
5099.952926, 4779.742057, 571.4303822, 614.9258218, 602.9830491, 
651.2847695, 591.8833499, 742.2387568, 4443.376841, 4716.792177
), cluster = c(2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -96L), class = "data.frame")
```

**First run of k-means clustering**

[First run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZ0iU.png)

**Second run of k-means clustering**

[Second run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBDz0.png)

Comment: I am not sure I understand your problem : is it a question a labeling the clusters or stability of clusters ? Could you provide a short example of what you get and what is expected ?

Comment: @cbo I have added two screenshots of the same samples ran twice through k-means. The first time the cluster is assigned as "3" and the second as "2". It about labeling and checking that the same label is applied to each call. (the label changes each time so that needs to be reflected in the code)

Comment: Your problem is clear now. You have included the data which is good, all we need now is the part of your code that call `kmeans` with the number of centers (ie clusters) used to reproduce your experiment.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a question of labels, you can always relabel your groups afterwards. I used 4 clusters based on the within sum of square criteria :

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages( library(dplyr) )
dfr <- as_tibble(dfr)

groups <- lapply(1:10, function(ct) kmeans(x = dfr[,c("RFU1", "RFU2")], centers = ct)$tot.withinss) # as.matrix(
# plot(unlist(groups))
```

**Method 1** : fix the random seed

```r
# --- Experiment 1
set.seed(123)
groups <- kmeans(x = dfr[,c("RFU1", "RFU2")], centers = 4)
dfr$cluster <- groups$cluster
dfr
#> # A tibble: 96 x 4
#>    id        RFU1    RFU2 cluster
#>    <chr>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <int>
#>  1 1       -0.296   -8.35       4
#>  2 2        0.964  235.         4
#>  3 3     3381.     638.         2
#>  4 4     3533.     650.         2
#>  5 5     3432.     617.         2
#>  6 6     3243.     604.         3
#>  7 7     2105.    4270.         1
#>  8 8     2220.    4200.         1
#>  9 9     3548.     690.         2
#> 10 10    3507.     713.         2
#> # ... with 86 more rows

# --- Experiment 2
set.seed(123)
groups <- kmeans(x = dfr[,c("RFU1", "RFU2")], centers = 4, )
dfr$cluster2 <- groups$cluster
dfr
#> # A tibble: 96 x 5
#>    id        RFU1    RFU2 cluster cluster2
#>    <chr>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <int>    <int>
#>  1 1       -0.296   -8.35       4        4
#>  2 2        0.964  235.         4        4
#>  3 3     3381.     638.         2        2
#>  4 4     3533.     650.         2        2
#>  5 5     3432.     617.         2        2
#>  6 6     3243.     604.         3        3
#>  7 7     2105.    4270.         1        1
#>  8 8     2220.    4200.         1        1
#>  9 9     3548.     690.         2        2
#> 10 10    3507.     713.         2        2
#> # ... with 86 more rows
```

**Method 2** : labels don't matter, groups do so don't do anything

**Method 3** : labels do matter

**3.1** my data is ordinate, label per cluster centers

```r
lab <- order(order(groups$centers[,1])) # c(2, 4, 3, 1)
# head( cbind(dfr$cluster2, lab[dfr$cluster2] ) )

dfr <- dfr %>% 
    mutate(label1 = lab[dfr$cluster2] )
```

**3.2** my data has important individuals, label using references

```r
# Suppose individuals 1, 4, 6 and 7 could name the classes

dfr <- dfr %>% tibble::rownames_to_column(var = "id") %>% 
    mutate(id = paste0("id_", id) )

refs <- tibble(id = dfr$id[c(1, 4, 6, 7)],
           cluster = dfr$cluster2[c(1, 4, 6, 7)]
           )

dfr %>% 
    mutate(label2 = refs$id[ c(2, 4, 3, 1)[cluster2] ]
        # label2 = letters[1:4][cluster2]
           )
#> # A tibble: 96 x 7
#>    id        RFU1    RFU2 cluster cluster2 label1 label2
#>    <chr>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <int>    <int>  <int> <chr> 
#>  1 1       -0.296   -8.35       4        4      1 1     
#>  2 2        0.964  235.         4        4      1 1     
#>  3 3     3381.     638.         2        2      4 7     
#>  4 4     3533.     650.         2        2      4 7     
#>  5 5     3432.     617.         2        2      4 7     
#>  6 6     3243.     604.         3        3      3 6     
#>  7 7     2105.    4270.         1        1      2 4     
#>  8 8     2220.    4200.         1        1      2 4     
#>  9 9     3548.     690.         2        2      4 7     
#> 10 10    3507.     713.         2        2      4 7     
#> # ... with 86 more rows
```

Comment: very detailed and seems like a reasonable solution. I was thinking of something more complicated like you know matching the clusters between runs of different sub samples. Seems like OP has moved onto something else :)

Comment: Thanks ! I am not sure I get it when you say "match[ing] the clusters between runs of different sub samples" , this seems like a bit of coding effort moreover :)